# Django iterate over dict without value names in the views file

Tags: python, django

I am using Django (python 2.7) and from a specific webpage I receive the following from `request.POST[‘items purchased’]`

```
print request.POST[‘items purchased’]

{3: [1, Decimal('15.23'), 'Effective Java', Decimal('15.23')], 14: [1, Decimal('34.65'), 'Microsoft Office 2013', Decimal('34.65')]}
```

When i do the following:

```
for key in request.POST[‘items purchased’]
    print key
```

It prints out everything from the first ‘{‘ to the last ‘}’. I just want the values.

How can I do a for loop and get all the values for each key (3 and 14)?

I have looked in SO and many other places for a answer but I have not found something that works. I have no key or value names for the values.

****EDIT*****
The request.POST was sent to the template in a dictionary. It eas not modified so i just sent it out to another view. I did not know it sent it as a string. Sorry guys.

I used another solution. Declared a global dictionary and used that one instead.

Comment: The value `request.POST['items purchased']` is a string, not a Python dictionary (you can check by printing `type(request.POST['items_purchased'])`). Converting the string back to a dictionary is tricky. Another option would be to convert the data to json before making the web request, then use `json.loads()` to convert back to a Python object.

Comment: I will look into that. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want `dictionary.values()`.

```
>>> dicty = {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}

>>> for i in dicty.values():
...     print i

one
two
```

If you want to get each value from within your dict values:

```
>>> dicty = {1: ['one1', 'one2'], 2: ['two1', 'two2']}

>>> for i in dicty.values():
...     for x in i:
...        print x

one1
one2
two1
two2
```

Here it is working on what you gave in your question:

```
  from decimal import Decimal

   x = {3: [1, Decimal('15.23'), 'Effective Java', Decimal('15.23')], 14: [1, Decimal('34.65'), 'Microsoft Office 2013', Decimal('34.65')]}
=> None
   for i in x.values(): 
..   print i 
..   
[1, Decimal('15.23'), 'Effective Java', Decimal('15.23')]
[1, Decimal('34.65'), 'Microsoft Office 2013', Decimal('34.65')]

for i in x.values(): 
.. for y in i: 
..   print y 
..     
1
15.23
Effective Java
15.23
1
34.65
Microsoft Office 2013
34.65
```

Comment: I get the following error: 'unicode' object has no attributes 'values'

Comment: I don't know why that would be. I just added your exact code to my example... the solution I gave works fine. The error you provided seems to indicate that you're attempting to loop through a string.

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner - Read the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900292/django-iterate-over-dict-without-value-names-in-the-views-file/33900381#comment55563300_33900292) on the question.